# C# signalr data annontations

Tags: c#, validation, signalr

I would like to write method validation processes which will be similar to data annontations presented in Web API.

In web api we can validate an object, for example:

```
public class Numbers
{
    [NumberOne]
    public string Number1 { get; set; }

    [NumberTwo]
    public string Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

and as long as we define the attributes `NumberOneAttribute` and `NumberTwoAttribute` its gonna be ok.

The difference is that web api has access to the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters` which it seems like signalr doesn't.

Is there anyway to validate requests by attributes? or I need to follow the worst case, validate each input in the invoked method?

Thanks,
Ori.

Comment: I don't think something exists out of the box for SignalR 2.2.x, but there is a [project on GitHub that does exactly what you are trying to achieve.](https://github.com/AGiorgetti/SignalR.Validation)

Comment: @radu-matei good enough, you may post it as an answer and i will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SignalR 2.2.x there is no native way of achieving this, but there is a [project on GitHub that that adds a Validation Module in the SignalR pipeline](https://github.com/AGiorgetti/SignalR.Validation).

Basically, in order to use it, you add a new module to the pipeline:

```
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ValidationModule());
```

Then, you can use attributes like `[Required]` for the models' properties and then decorate the desired methods with the `[Validate]` attribute.

> Note that this is a proof of contept project.

Best regards!